# What is the name of the script used in the earliest Qurʾānic manuscripts?

Tags: quran

I've seen it transliterated into English as *ma'ili* which supposedly means "inclined" or "slanting." I'm looking for the **Arabic** word. Is it مائلي?

[image]

Comment: @Sazid The picture shows verses 18 to 29 of Surat al-Maa'idah, starting with "[The Jews] and the Christians said we are the children of God and His beloved ones..." (verse 18) to "I want you to carry my sins and your sins..." (29).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is written مائل (maa'il) in Arabic, which does indeed mean slanted. Another name for this early script is حجازي‎ ([hijazi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hijazi_script)) in reference to it originating from the Hijaz region of the Arabian Peninsula.

Later Quranic manuscripts switched to [Kufic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kufic) which is a reference to the city of Kufa in Iraq where it was first developed.